# save raw post data to file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the first time i am using stackoverflow . I made this script in `php` to save raw post data to a file . I will only post the part that is the most important :

```
<?php
$jsonString = file_get_contents("php://input");
$jfile = rand(100000,999999);
file_put_contents($jfile,$jsonString);
?>
```

I need this script to be converted in an `asp.net` but I don't know much about .net, I searched all over but I couldn't find anything. I would also need to know how a client can send the data.

something like this ?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            public HttpResponseMessage Post(string person)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public                \TestFolder        \WriteText.txt", person);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good example of what you need in a nutshell:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

In order to use the code in ASP.NET you will need to create an ASP.NET application (perhaps Web Api or MVC). Take a look at this tutorial:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_app.asp

To answer your other question about sending data from the client here's a set of examples based on using jQuery (I assume by client you mean an application that runs in a browser):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

**EDITED:**

Here's a very simple example of sending data from the client to your WebApi service

your clients sends data using jQuery's post method:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.post("http://myservicehost/api/Persons",
    {
        name: "Donald Duck",
        city: "Duckburg"
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
```

your WebApi controller receives it:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string person)
{
    //do whatever you want to do with this person
    //
    //
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt response Nikolai but this doesn't help me very much , the link from microsoft indeed shows me how to write the data to a file but what about reading the string sent by the client , I am supposed to be receiving json strings.

Comment: @JamesWhitney you need to create a Web Api controller and within it you have to have Get (or Post) action method with a string parameter. Or you can have the same method with a typed parameter. If your json string can be deserialized to that type it will happen automatically. Your controller's method might look like this: 

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateBook(Book book) { ... }

Comment: having said all that my answer still answers your question, so I would appreciate marking my answer as accepted

Comment: sorry Nikolai I still didn't understand , I would gladly mark your response as accepted if I really understood it but I want to wait and see if I get better opinions from other users. Thanks

Comment: see my latest edit. hope it makes it easier to understand. but it seems to me you need to first read up on ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: looks more or less correct. your HomeController needs to inherit from ApiController to use WebApi. Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api. Make sure to use correct "usings"

Comment: it's not very constructive to delete your comments. Makes it hard for everyone to follow

Comment: I was trying to paste code here , thats why i deleted them , i still try to use that code but am getting a lot of errors

Comment: Errors are anticipated. You need to get up to speed with ASP.NET first. There might be many causes for errors - like libraries missing, syntax errors, improper code, etc

Comment: I get this error 'HttpRequestBase' does not contain a definition for 'CreateResponse' and no extension method  'CreateResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequestBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: step by step instructions: 1. create an empty ASP.NET app, 2. install Web Api using nuget, 3. try your thing again.....just follow the tutorial link I sent earlier. It'll save you an awful lot of time

Comment: @JamesWhitney it's not fair to get useful support and not leave any positive feedback. This is not how this community works